# Automatic Matrix fill for exchange rates

Tags: java, math, matrix

I have a 2 dimensional Array. Each Row and each Column represents an exchange rate for currencies. For example

```
     EUR   USD
EUR   1    1.3
USD  0.7    1
```

Now the information that I get in the beginning is missing a lot of fields. 
For example:

```
     EUR   USD   BTC
EUR   1    1.3   632
USD         1
BTC               1
```

This is enough information to fill the complete Matrix. My Matrix may or may not have enough information and will have between 10-20 rows/columns.
Now my question: Is there an algorithm that can fill this Matrix in some library? If not what would be the best way to fill this Matrix?

Comment: What's wrong with `matrix[i][k] = matrix[0][k] / matrix[0][i]` or maybe the other way around?

Comment: Yeah thats the static way for a fixed matrix size. I am almost finished with me recursive solution. But it will not be optimal. Since it is a math problem I thought there might be an algorithm already.

Comment: Recursion will work, and is sorta how some spreadsheets solve the problem. Of course you could also iterate over the grid until nothing more can be solved, which wouldn't be as pretty but -- depending on how much info you're starting with, and what patterns it will be in -- might be faster. Taking advantage of the fact that there are inherent symmetries in the problem might speed up the solution.